# How to sort a list of string that have float numbers in the middle?

Tags: python, string, sorting, floating-point, double

I need to sort a list of strings based on a float value in the middle of the string.

I've seen some answers getting a key `keys.sort(key=float)`, but on those answers they have only the float numbers inside the list. In this case I need to convert that piece of the string to float and sort it based on that value. At the end I will need the whole string.

```
list_of_msg = []
msg1 = "buy.apple<100; 21.15; Jonh>"
msg2 = "buy.apple<100; 20.00; Jane>"
msg3 = "buy.apple<50; 20.10; Anne>"
list_of_msg.append(msg1)
list_of_msg.append(msg2)
list_of_msg.append(msg3)
# sort method goes here
print(list_of_msg)
```

Expected this to be sorted based on the values 21.15, 20.00, 20.10

```
 ['buy.apple<100; 20.00; Jane>', 'buy.apple<50; 20.10; Anne>', 
 'buy.apple<100; 21.15; Jonh']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sorted` / `sort` with `key` argument:

```
sorted(list_of_msg, key=lambda x: float(x.split(';')[1].strip()))
```

We split elements in original list based on `';'` and take second split which is passed as `key` argument.